# on multiple comboboxs selectedindexchanged hv to enabled a button - C#

Tags: c#

I have 8 `comboboxes` and if user changes any one of the `combobox` value , i have to enable a button.
I added the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for every combobox. and try to check like this.

```
if (
  cmbDInput_SelectedIndexChanged || cmbSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged ||
  cmbSatName_SelectedIndexChanged || cmbDRepeat_SelectedIndexChanged ||
  cmbSeq_SelectedIndexChanged
)
```

but it throws an error

> Operator `||` cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'method group'

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a method for example EnableButton

```
private void EnableButton()
{
   myButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

then in all your selected index changed events you call this method

```
private void cmbDInput_SelectedIndexChanged(.....)
{
   EnableButton();
}
```

do that for al your select index changed events

or you could have 1 event for the all dropdown boxes

Answer (score 0):

You are using method name i.e event `cmbDInput_SelectedIndexChanged` in if statement expression `||` operator should be applied to boolean.

```
if ((cmbDInput_SelectedIndexChanged) || cmbSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged || cmbSatName_SelectedIndexChanged || cmbDRepeat_SelectedIndexChanged || cmbSeq_SelectedIndexChanged)
```

Would be

```
if ((cmbDInput.SelectedIndex !- -1) || cmbSwitch.SelectedIndex != -1|| cmbSatName.SelectedIndex !- -1 || cmbDRepeat_.SelectedIndex != -1 || cmbSeq.SelectedIndex != -1)
```

or you can get the source of event i.e. the combo whom selected index is changed as follows

```
protected void cmbDInput_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox ChangedCombox = sender as ComboBox;
}
```